# Help with baking results in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I am a software engineer struggling with getting good in Blender. Currently I am trying to get better at baking, specifically in cycles. These are some screen shots from inside unreal engine. I have re-UVunwrapped this model a few times trying to get better results, and played with smoothing and seams. I also tried to correct some smoothing issues, things that look like glares across the model. I am wondering if these poor results are a result of UVunwrapping, Baking, the seams, or smoothing. Here is a link to the Blend file https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alrv4w-MciWDkY16VX5XIhvgJYUrpw
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are baking the normals form a high poly model, but it's not totally aligned with the low poly model.

[image: high poly not aligned]

You can see how the dark areas produced by the normals are where the high and the low poly models don't match.